# issue when trying to put a <span> inside a div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to follow the answers in the similar questions but i still get the same result , what I'm trying to do is putting a `span` witch is an Oval inside a `div` , i have implemented this simple

```
createPong = function () {
    var blockSize = 50,
        element = document.createElement('span'),
        pong;

    element.style.position = 'absolute';
    element.style.display = 'block';
    element.style.width = blockSize + 'px';
    element.style.height = blockSize + 'px';
    element.style.background = getRandomColor();
    element.style.borderRadius = blockSize + 'px';

    pong = {
        id: pongId = 1,
        element: element,
        size: blockSize,
        dirX: Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1,
        dirY: Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1,
        speed: 5,
        collided: false
    };

    placePong(pong);

    return pong;
},
```

---

```
 run = function (numberOfPongs) {
    var i = 0,
        containerElement = document.getElementsByClassName('mainDiv')[0], // <----                        pong;

        pong = createPong();
        document.containerElement.appendChild(pong.element); // <---- 
        pongs.push(pong);

    gameId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
},
```

but now i have the span (Oval) displayed at the top left corner of the browser and not in the `mainDiv` , before i implement this simple the Oval was in movement but now still in the same position

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fyL9yu36/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
document.containerElement.appendChild(pong.element);
```

Appends it to nothing. It needs to go in `containerElement`.

```
containerElement.appendChild(pong.element);
```

Also, your fiddle was appending it to the `body`.

http://jsfiddle.net/fyL9yu36/1/

Comment: thank you , do you have an idea why the ball still in the same position , because it's supposed to be in movement !

Comment: That is really a separate question